# Search by XPath under a given element

Tags: php, dom, xpath

The only way I know in PHP to perform an XPath query on the DOM is [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/fr/class.domxpath.php), which only works on a `DOMDocument`:

```
public __construct ( DOMDocument $doc )
```

**Is there a similar mechanism to search relatively to a `DOMElement`?**

The problem being, I need to search an abritrary XPath (that I have no control over) relatively to a `DOMElement`.

I've tried to do:

```
$domElement->getNodePath() . '/' . $xPath;
```

But if the XPath contains a `|` (*or* character), this approach doesn't work.

Comment: I think this is something you will like: http://querypath.org/ It's the only way i use to manipulate the DOM in php. It's very neat ;)

Comment: I know QueryPath, but I'd like to avoid using it if it's possible to do it with the built-in DOM only.

Comment: QueryPath uses PHP's SimpleXML, so it's okay, go ahead and use it.

Comment: No, it's not *ok*, I know there are external libraries that do the job, I'm just trying to limit the number of dependencies!

Comment: Also, I need to get back an array of `DOMElement`s that are the same instances as in the document I'm working on, not pale copies. So I can't mix DOM and another library, especially if it's based on SimpleXML.

Comment: @Twisted1919: This is more a comment than a real answer. The library you suggest is a good suggestion, no question, but it's just not an answer to suggest it. Turn it into a comment instead.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yes there is. The element is also part of the document, so you use the xpath object of the document, but when you run the query, there is a second parameter which is the context-node to which the query in the first parameter is *resolved* to:

```
// query all child-nodes of $domElement
$result = $xpath->query('./*', $domElement);
```

*Resolved* means, that if the xpath is:

1. relative, it is relative to that `$domElement` context-node.
2. absolute, it resolves to the document node (still/again).

Only *relative* path applies in context here, which is why I prefixed it with a dot in front: `./*`. A simple `*` would work, too, just would not make this specifically visible.

See [*`DOMXpath::query()`*](http://php.net/DOMXpath.query).

Comment: @Benjamin: No problemo, there are some catches, the path should be written relative, that is why I put the dot in front. Should give you a good start with context based xpath queries. In SimpleXML it is automatically relative to the element where the xpath method is called on.

Comment: That should be all right, I'm mostly using XPath expressions coming from a CSS-selector-to-XPath library, which basically all begin with something like `descendant-or-self::`

Comment: @hakre my dear friend **the path should be written relative** this is the statement that I was search for and is really important! I was so confused why I always get all the elements when I use something like `//div[@class='some row']` and now i know that to search in a specific **DOMElement** you need to specify relative path like `./div[@class='some row']`. Thanks !

Comment: There is also `.//` (I.E. `.//div[@class='something']`) which will search for things under a given element, but they need not be *immediate* children of that element.