# domxpath - Extract li tags from second ul

Tags: php, domxpath

I am trying to extract only the second ul's li tags from the following. Unfortunately, there are no classes or ids in the html to help

```
<ul>
    <li>Some text</li>
    <li>Some text</li>
    <li>Some text</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>Some more text</li>
    <li>Some more text</li>
    <li>Some more text</li>
</ul>
```

I have tried (a few things, actually):

```
    $ul = $xpath->query('//ul')->item(1);
    $query = '/li';
    $lis = $xpath->evaluate($query, $ul);
```

Thinking this will get me the second ul, and then I can extract from there. It does get me the second ul's html, but I'm obviously misunderstanding something with `->evaluate?  because my li's are all the li's, not just from the second ul.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can directly access them using XPath:

```
$xpath->query('//ul[2]/li');
```

Example:

```
$html = <<<EOF
<ul>
    <li>Some text</li>
    <li>Some text</li>
    <li>Some text</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>Some more text</li>
    <li>Some more text</li>
    <li>Some more text</li>
</ul>
EOF;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$selector = new DOMXpath($doc);

// iterate through them...
foreach($selector->query('//ul[2]/li') as $li) {
    echo $li->nodeValue . PHP_EOL;
}
```

~

Comment: No, that gives me the second li for both ul's - I want all the li's from the second ul

Comment: but you gave me the answer anyway :-)  //ul[2]/li  Thanks

Comment: yep, thanks. Have to wait 5min to accept, but that's what I'm after

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the context-node (as in your question), add a dot in front (dot in xpath is the current node) to be relative to the context-node, not going up to the root:

```
$query = './li';
          #
$lis = $xpath->evaluate($query, $ul);
```

Or just without the slash in front:

```
$query = 'li';              
$lis = $xpath->evaluate($query, $ul);
```

See as well / compare with: [*Search by XPath under a given element*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16364662/367456).

Comment: It is correct what you are saying. But you can just use `li` as well. Like in a filesystem. You won't need the leading `./`

Comment: AFAIK in simplexml xpath yes, in domxpath i'm not entirely sure if that is always the case. so I there often use with dot. technically just using `li` should be correct xpath relative to the context-node as well, yes.

Comment: cannot really imagine as simplexml is linked against the same `libxml`.. you should try it. maybe you'll save some `./` in future ;)

Comment: Yeah, maybe it's just me going crazy without reason :) For the answer here I at least can barely talk me out of this here saying that because of the slash you need to out the dot, you know :) - fixed + big thx @hek2mgl

Comment: `maybe it's just me going crazy without reason` I know such things ;) .. +1 for the answer